# Lookup with multiple criteria, one a MAX value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table, vlookup, excel-2013

I am trying to lookup the `LOCATION` of an employee (`NAME`) and their `MANAGER` from the most recent month (largest month number) in a particular `QUARTER` in data like this:

```
NAME             LOCATION        MANAGER         QUARTER    MONTH
Ryan Smith       Sioux Falls     Rick James        3          7
Jane Doe         Tampa           Bobby Brown       3          7
John Rogers      Tampa           Tracy Lane        3          7
Ryan Smith       Sioux Falls     Rick James        3          8
Jane Doe         Denver          Thomas Craig      3          8
John Rogers      Tampa           Cody Davis        3          8
```

So if I know the name of the employee and the quarter I'm looking up, the results should display who their last manager was and the location they were in, as these may change month to month.

I have used an INDEX and MATCH array formula:

```
{=INDEX($B$2:$B$7,MATCH(A12,IF($D$2:$D$7=D12,$A$2:$A$7),0))}
```

but this just provides the first match and not necessarily the most recent month in that quarter. I attempted to include a MAX function which looked something like this:

```
{=INDEX($B$2:$B$7,MAX($E2:$E7,MATCH(A12,IF($D$2:$D$7=D12,$A$2:$A$7),0)))}
```

but that didn't quite get me there either.

What formula do I need to get this to work?

Comment: How are you entering the Name and Quarter? This is going to be a looong formula...

Answer (score 1):

I think I'd choose a PivotTable for its versatility and speed:

[image: SO32404865 example]

Comment: Probably the best solution. If you add a column to the underlying data with a MAX() function on Quarter and Month and put it in the filter, whenever you refresh the pivot table you should get the most recent entry for each employee.

Comment: Agreed. I was working on a solution with a formula, but unless you add a lookup column, there really isn't a clean way to accomplish this. I'll post what I did...

Comment: I'm all for alternate solutions, especially when they avoid things like incredibly long formulas. Plus, pivot tables are pretty easy to learn and figure out. If this spreadsheet were passed on to someone else, a complex array formula might not be a good option if the next gen. user isn't great with formulas.

Answer (score 1):

I think a pivot table is probably the best option and can easily be modified with the filters when new entries are added to the underlying data. I was working on a solution with a formula, but it requires you to add a lookup column.

The formula for the lookup column is: `=E6&" "&H6&" "&I6`

[image]

I wasn't clear on how the OP was going to be "entering" his employee name and quarter, so I had to make an assumption that it would be in a separate column:

[image]

And the formula in column B (which is cumbersome) is:

```
=VLOOKUP(A6&" "&MAX(IF(H1:H100=NUMBERVALUE(RIGHT(A6,1)),I1:I100)),$D$6:$G$11,3,FALSE)&", managed by "&VLOOKUP(A6&" "&MAX(IF(H1:H100=NUMBERVALUE(RIGHT(A6,1)),I1:I100)),$D$6:$G$11,4,FALSE)
```

But it works, and as long as the lookup range is adjusted, is scaleable.

Comment: Actually, I don't know if this will work since it's taking the max Month, but not the max month for that quarter... Typing Ryan Smith 2 would yield and error b/c it would evaluate as Ryan Smith 2 8. Hm... Back to the drawing board.

Comment: Oh it's much, much worse when you consider that you have to find the max month for the given quarter. Then, with the option of entering the search string, you have to convert the quarter to a number. Oy what a headache.

Comment: The Name, Quarter and Month all come from a pivot already. I bring in the monthly statistics in order to recreate a Quarterly Performance Award. So any Name in the Quarter is filled out, once I have this data completed I will be putting it into a Pivot for reporting. But when i post the report, i need to have the employees linked to their current Manager so their Managers can pivot to their own names and see the quarterly results of the team.

Comment: You're going to need to post some screenshots if you want additional help in getting your report formatted.

Comment: To bring more clarity to this since my pics wouldn't take when i posted, my attempted view of excel is located in a Monthly Data worksheet with alot of formulas creating a Monthly Award. I have the Quarterly Data in another worksheet which takes information from the Monthly Data to create the Quarterly Award. Both worksheets are put into two seperate pivot tables for reporting. For simplicity of this, the Quarterly Data will appear the same as my drawing but with the Monthly Column removed, and no data in the the Department and Manager fields (what i'm attempting to grab from the Monthly).